# Unable to get maxheight on resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have html and script like this. I want box1 box2 box display with the same height. But when I resize browser to check, the max height is not correct.

```
<div class="pro_intro>"
   <div class="box box1">
     something 1
   </div>
   <div class="box box2">
     something 2      
   </div>
   <div class="box box3">
     something 3
   </div>
</div>

$(window).on("resize", function () {
        var max = -1;
        $(".pro_intro .box").each(function() {  
            var h = $(this).outerHeight(); 
            max = h > max ? h : max;
        });
        $(".pro_intro .box").css("height",max);
        $(".pro_intro .box").css({'visibility':'visible'});
}).resize();
```

Any suggestion for this. Thank you so much

Comment: Downvoter comment.

Comment: There is no way for me to know why others downvoted, but I can tell you what I find wrong about your approach: you rely on jQuery to do a task that should clearly be performed by CSS. Your comment under one of the answers: *"CSS is not solution for dynamic responsive with many different devices"* is simply not true and only shows you don't know CSS can perform this, which is probably why you prefer using jQuery. If your goal is larger than simply layout display (and maybe want some specific animations), etc... you should add details to your question, so we see the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current code is you are missing the closing double quote for `<div class="pro_intro>`, which makes your code invalid, hence jQuery fails to work properly.

Also, there's a minor conceptual flaw with your script: you're not resetting the height of the divs. Which means `.outerHeight()` returns the current set height (by the previous iteration), not the height needed for your content if the element had `height:auto`. Here's the fix for it, using your (wrong, IMHO,) approach:

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  var max = -1;
  $(".pro_intro .box")
    .height('auto')
    .each(function() {
      max = Math.max(
        $(this).outerHeight(), 
        max
      );
    });
  $(".pro_intro .box").css({
    height: max + 'px',
    visibility: 'visible'
  });
}).resize();
```

```css
.pro_intro .box {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pro_intro">
  <div class="box box1">
    something 1
  </div>
  <div class="box box2">
    something 2
  </div>
  <div class="box box3">
    something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3 something 3
    something 3 something 3 something 3
  </div>
</div>
```

I said "wrong approach" because I advise you not to use JavaScript for this task. A bound listener on `resize` is really something you want to avoid for performance sake. You should at least throttle it.

---

I would use flexbox for the task:

```css
.pro_intro {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

Here's an example:

```css
.pro_intro {
  display: flex;
  /* totally optional: 
    min-height: 35vh; 
  */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.pro_intro>.box {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 .5rem;
  padding: 0 .75rem;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .pro_intro {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .pro_intro .box {
    flex: 1 0 51%;
    margin: .5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pro_intro">
  <div class="box box1">
    <p>something 1
  </div>
  <div class="box box2">
    <p>something 2
  </div>
  <div class="box box3">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at. Morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget. Donec pretium vulputate sapien nec. A pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Sit amet risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right. Because I do not reset outerHeight. Now it is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use CSS's `height` and `max-height` properties?

Something like:

`.box1, .box2 { 
    height: 100%; 
    max-height: 300px; 
}`

Comment: CSS is not solution for dynamic responsive with many different devices

Comment: @BuiPhuc Yes it is? Check out media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing quotation mark for your pro_intro div.

Try this

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    $(".pro_intro .box").each(function() {  
        $(this).css("height","");
    });
    var max = -1;
    $(".pro_intro .box").each(function() {  
        var h = $(this).outerHeight(); 
        max = h > max ? h : max;
    });
    $(".pro_intro .box").each(function() {  
    $(this).css({"height": max, "visibility": "visible"});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your jquery code with this one below

```
 var max = -1;
        $(".pro_intro .box").each(function() {  
            var h = $(this).outerHeight(); 
            max = h > max ? h : max;
        });
        $(".pro_intro .box").css("height",max);
        $(".pro_intro .box").css({'visibility':'visible'});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m3rs30tx/